# How to get image size from a file with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to get a width from a file to use it as a variable. Trying that:

```
iconOS_img = new Image();
iconOS_img.src = '/details/images/icon.png';
var iconOS_img_width = iconOS_img.width;

alert(iconOS_img_width);
```

However, it returns `0`.

Comment: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wait until the image loads. Try this

```
iconOS_img.onload = function() {
    alert(this.width);
}
```

Comment: No problem. Mark it as the answer and you can be on your merry way :).

Answer (score 2):

You queried it too fast. You have to give the image some time to load. Best would be to bind the `load` handler and read width there.